# Element not clickable when screen goes off n browser is blocked by others

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

I am having this strange issue.  The click works when I can watching or monitoring it, but it will fail when the screen is off.  I will get the error element not visible or clickable.  When I activate my screen I can clearly see the element.  N it will continue on next iteration when screen is on.  Any idea?  using playwright n python.

Answer (score 0):

seems to have solved some of the issues.

I use:

```
page.locator.hover
page.locator.click
```

except:

```
page.locator.hover
page.locator.click(force=true)
```

this seems to be working at the moment. I still get exception, n return to the loop again, n it works.

update: actually, it sometimes works sometimes doesn't. driving me crazy